# Flask server deployed with IIS cannot interact with main computer's programs

Tags: python, reactjs, flask, iis, server

I have a Flask + React application that I deployed to my IIS server. I have both servers running on different ports. The front end scans forms and sends them to the backend for OCR. If the backend cannot read the from, it has the user select the ROI for specific data.

My issue is that my Flask server on IIS cannot interact with applications on my main computer. It cannot open a PDF with Adobe Acrobat, open a PDF on Chrome, or allow the user to selectROI() in the Python window.

My project works when I run it locally.

I have added .py to the MIME types for the Flask server site in IIS. That did not help. The backend server waits for the user to select the ROI from the Python window but the Python window never appears. The method ends up timing out.

Comment: Could you try to set the application pool identity to the LocalSystem or NetworkService by following this steps: open IIS Manager -> select Application Pools in the Connections pane. Then right-click on the application pool which is associate with the site and select Advance settings. Then change the Identity to LocalSystem or NetworkService

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: You do need to know that Windows has session isolation, so you cannot do whatever you wanted, https://halfblood.pro/web-application-differences-in-visual-studio-and-iis-60fec7e311b3